# Is there a way to disable the intro video of Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Given that the loading part is fast enough by itself, I have seen the intro video showing Bethesda enough by now. When launching the game I want to play as fast as possible, espectially when I quickly need to check something.

Is it possible to disable the intro video?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it is.

Go to your Skyrim folder. Inside this folder there should be a folder called "Data". Inside this folder should be a folder called "Video". Delete the video called: BGS_Logo.bik

It should be the only video inside the folder. I have also tested and verified this works (and doesn't break the game). It just puts you on the start menu where you can load or start a new game.

Possible locations, replace the path where applicable, check the (x86) folder on 64-bit systems.

- %ProgramFiles%\Steam\SteamApps\Common\Skyrim\Data\Video\BGS_Logo.bik
- %ProgramFiles%\The Elder Scrolls V Skyrim\Data\Video\BGS_Logo.bik

Comment: You should rename the video really, if you delete it you can't go back.

Comment: @Tacroy You can verify files in Steam and it'll restore them. In other words, you can redownload that and only that through Steam.

Comment: @crazysim Riiiiiiight, man, I keep on forgetting the wonders of living in the cloud...

Comment: @crazysim However that will probably cause Steam to also check all other files for corruption, effectively wasting a lot of processor time, especially compared to the little space the renamed video takes up

Comment: @Zommuter Skyrim is actually fairly kind of small at ~4.5GB and if you're running Skyrim, processor/hdd/ssd time is probably pretty cheap for you anyway. Finally, you're not running verification all the time and only if you want the intro video back.

Comment: @crazysim True, I just thought it worth mentioning so no one complains later :-7

Comment: This does NOT work. Deleted the video from the skyrim data folder and the video still plays. it must be stored elsewhere.

Comment: @s4ndm4n2006 Try [this method](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/124237/4797), instead.

Comment: I deleted the video. It now doesn't appear, but instead I get a delay before game menu shows about the same length as the video.

Answer (score 14):

- Go to `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\Skyrim\` or `C:\Users\<username>\Documents\My Games\Skyrim`

  - Note: Replace 'Documents' above with 'My Documents' if on Windows 7.
- Open `Skyrim.ini`. Navigate to the `[General]` section.
- Add the following line at the end of the section:
  `sIntroSequence=`
- Save the file.

<sup>Source: [PC Gaming Wiki, "**Skyrim - Skip Intro**"](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Skyrim#Skip_Intro)</sup>

Comment: This should be the top answer. Doesn't compromise the Skyrim data folder, only modifies user data.